# Bigquery how to change the workplace style or GUI

Tags: google-bigquery

Seems BigQuery has released the new interface, not really like it.
Does anyone know how to change back to the typical style?

Thank you so much
[image]

More prefer to change back to below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you can by clicking `disabling editor tabs` > `Opt out without feedback`. This will switch you back to the old UI.

**Note**: This feature will be permanently remove after this month. I suggest you to open an issue tracker [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685)    and provide feedback about the new ui and its differences with the old UI.

Comment: Hello @SharpLu, did the answer address your question?